# How to resolve the Undefined References?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, wxwidgets

In trying to making a file on ubuntu using terminal, I am getting a series of these undefined reference statements:

**Node.cpp:(.text+0x978): undefined reference to `glLineWidth'
Node.cpp:(.text+0x996): undefined reference to`glPushMatrix'
Node.cpp:(.text+0x9fb): undefined reference to `glTranslatef'
Node.cpp:(.text+0xa0b): undefined reference to`glColor3fv'
.
.
Parser.cpp:(.text+0x1a69): undefined reference to `wxLogVerbose(wchar_t const*, ...)'
Parser.cpp:(.text+0x1a8e): undefined reference to`wxLogVerbose(wchar_t const*, ...)'
Parser.cpp:(.text+0x1e4d): undefined reference to `wxLogError(wchar_t const*, ...)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [aqua3d] Error 1**

Kindly let me know what is solution to this.

FYI, I've already installed freeglut, libgtk and libwxgtk.

Comment: What command do you issue that generates this response ?

Comment: I was making the file using,
make -f Makefile.txt

Comment: @user3462765, try "make -f Makefile"

Comment: this is what I get, If I try it without .txt:       

make: Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `Makefile'.  Stop.

Comment: @Developer, you need to run configure to create an actual Makefile and then just run make

Comment: yes thanks I tried that too, actually the problem is these undefined references.

Comment: Here is a tutorial i have written to get started with wxWidgets on Linux: https://sites.google.com/site/opensourceconstriubtions/ettl-martin-1/tutorials/how-to-install-wxwidgets-on-a-linux-system It guides you through the installation and contains sample code as well.